# How can I extract the text where the first word starts with the upper letter and the last symbol is before the dot (.)?

Tags: excel

I want to use in the Excel the formula, which returns the values:

```
Original Text               Desired Result
7. Hello.abc                Hello
7.1 Hello.abc               Hello
11. Hello mary.bab          Hello mary
12.1. Hello.bab (hi there)  Hello
12.2.4.a. Hello hi.abc      Hello hi
Hello.no                    Hello
```

I have already tried that formula, which returns the values between 2 dots:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(". " & A1&REPT(" ";6);".";REPT(";";255));2*255;255);";";"")
```

But if the original text is `12.1. Hello.bab (hi there)` the formula returns: `1` when I need to return: `Hello`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this?

=MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1)+1,1),IFERROR(FIND(".",MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND(" ",A1)+1,1),90))-1,90))

Comment: Thank you very much. It's not working if there are NO dot (.) after the words, for example: 14. Hello hi ...It returns the same value: 14. Hello hi ..but it will be Hello hi.

Answer (score 2):

This formula should work for you:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),MIN(INDEX(FIND(MID("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",ROW($1:$26),1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1)))&"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"),)),LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It works!!! Is there some formula which works when the last dot(.) OR : ? For example: 12.2.4.a. Hello hi:abc ->     Hello hi